# Return from partial displaying content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a partial in Rails.

View:

```
<%= render :partial => "partial" %>
```

Partial:

```
<% if no_entries %>
    <h1>No entries</h1>
    <% return %>
<% end %>

<!-- Display entries -->
```

When I run this partial with an error, the output is blank. How can I make it display the `<h1>`?

NOTE: In my actual code, I want to return multiple lines and I am trying to avoid an `if else end` with a thousand lines in between the else and end.

Thanks!

Comment: When you say the output is blank, do you mean the entire page? If that's the case I'd suspect it to be the return statement.

Comment: The output from the partial is blank. And yes, it is the return statement. I am looking for the correct code to return with the content.

Comment: You could try `<% if flash[:error] %><h1>Error!</h1><% end %>`

Comment: It looks like your if statement, `if error`, is returning false if you don't see the `<h1>` tag. Where are you defining `error`? Also, try putting `<h1>Error!</h1>` outside the if statement to see if you are calling the partial correctly.

Comment: This isn't about the partial having a problem, or about display an error. i know how to do both of those. The code above is for demonstration of what I would like to do, which is: return content from a partial without executing any of the remaining code.